# Switching window not working in selenium webelement java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have list of webelements, iterating this list in foreach loop, in that loop on click of webelement,switching from one screen to second screen, in second screen, i have back button after doing my work i am pressing back button and again coming back to the first screen, which has that list of webelements. This whole scenario is working only for first iteration, but in second iteration getting exception like this,

> "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
>   Command duration or timeout: 50.13 seconds"

Following is my code,

> ```
>   try {           /**
>        * In this scenario i am iterating through webelementlist, in first iteration i have clicked first 
>        * webelement, then fetching some values from second screen after doing my work returning back
>        * to the first one. 
>        */             List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.className("classname"));
>
>       for(WebElement webElement: elementList){
>
>           webElement.click();
>
>           //fetching some values
>           String str = driver.findElement(By.className("classname")).getText();
>
>           System.out.println("Value : "+str);
>
>           //returning back to the first page
>           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pane']/div/div[1]/div/button")).click();
>       }       } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        }
> ```

working on it for a long time, but even not getting any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the page, or the DOM is refreshed, the driver losses all the WebElements it found earlier. You need to relocate the list each iteration

```
int size = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.className("classname"));
    elementList.get(i).click(); // click the element by index
    size = elementList.size();  // change "size" to the list size

    //fetching some values
    String str = driver.findElement(By.className("classname")).getText();

    System.out.println("Value : "+str);

    //returning back to the first page
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='pane']/div/div[1]/div/button")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException can occur
 any time, it should be handled and the execution should continue...

    int count=0;
    while(count<4)
    {
    try{
    int size = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
        List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.className("classname"));
        elementList.get(i).click(); // click the element by index
        size = elementList.size();  // change "size" to the list size

        //fetching some values
        String str = driver.findElement(By.className("classname")).getText();

        System.out.println("Value : "+str);

        //returning back to the first page
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='pane']/div/div[1]/div/button")).click();
    } } count=count+4;
     catch(StaleElementReferenceException e)
    {
    System.out.println("recover from exception");
    count=count+1; continue;
    }
}
```